# Best way to define Django global variable on apache starup

Tags: python, django

I have some configuration in a json file and on the database and I want to load those configuration on Django startup (Apache server startup).. I will be using those global variable within all the application. 
For Example: External server connection api or number of instances.

What is the best way to define the global variables. I want to load the json file when server starts and use the variable value util server stop. ?

Comment: Those who mark as negative could you able to provide best solution for this ?

Comment: Why can't you use Django's settings?

Comment: I have some configuration inside database also. I think cant use db connections inside settings. I want to load the config values from json and at the same time inside db connection. and set it. Sorry I mentioned only json file in the question.

Comment: My question is: why can't you set these settings directly in the settings of your project, instead of loading them from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the thing you're probably looking for is `environment variables` - you can always use a small script to set the environment variables from the JSON that you have at present.

Setting these in your .bashrc file or, more preferably a virtualenv will let you:

1. Take sensitive settings, like `SECRET_KEY` [out of version control.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/)
2. Offer database settings, either by supplying them as a DB URL or as seperate environment variables.
3. Set both Django settings and other useful variables outside of the immediate Django project.

The [django-environ docs have a useful tutorial](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on how to set it up.   [The Django Cookie-Cutter project](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) makes extensive use of Environment Variables (including DB and mailserver settings), and is a great place to pick up hints and approaches.